# Build of expect v5.43 fails with Tcl v8.5.8

Tags: linux, tcl, expect

I'm trying to build "expect" from source v5.43, using Tcl built from source v8.5.8 on Redhat Linux. Tcl built fine, but my attempt to build expect fails. I run configure, then make, which gives me the error: `TCL_REG_BOSONLY' undeclared when compiling exp_inter.c. I did some digging around, and found the TCL_REG_BOSONLY value defined in Tcl file tclInt.h, but there is no #include for that in the exp_inter.c file.

My question is, can "expect" be built from source with Tcl version 8.5.8, or does it require an earlier version? Version 5.43 is the latest for "expect" that I can find, and the current Tcl version is 8.5.8, but something doesn't seem compatible between the two.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I downloaded a newer version (v5.44.1.15) of expect from sourceforge.net/projects/expect/. My original download was from the official expect website at expect.nist.gov, which is apparantly very outdated. Anyway, the newer version built fine.

Answer (score 2):

Did you run `ldconfig` to relink the libraries after installing tcl?  It looks like expect isn't finding required libraries.  Do you see any errors when running `configure`?  Have all dependencies met?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried running ldconfig. No errors from configure, which I ran w/ the --with-tcl and --with-tclinclud options to id the Tcl directories. I found https://www.blastwave.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=8 on this issue, suggesting TCL_REG_BOSONLY definition was moved from tcl.h to tclInt.h, which does include it in the source I have. The exp_inter.c file from expect source doesn't include tclInt.h though, but does include tcl.h. So, I'm wondering about version compatibility. I tried adding include tclInt.h to exp_inter.c, and make no longer gets the error, but now gets others.

Comment: The other errors make gets now are undefined references to Tcl_CloseObjCmd and Tcl_ReturnObjCmd in exp_command.o. These are both defined in the tclInt.h file, which is included in exp_command.c.